# Control Raspberry Pi with phone

Tags: android, ios, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am new to Raspberry Pi. I wish to turn on/off a light and play some sounds on the Pi from my phone both Android and iPhone. It is a kids toy that I am prototyping.

I need the setup to be easy for any user to download the app and just connect to the Pi with little trouble. I dont want the Pi connected to the internet so no external api services.

I have search for tutorials but surprising nothing other than using a service.

Could anyone poin me in the right direct. I dont have a preference over bluetooth of wifi. Just one that is easy for a kid or parent to setup.

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, a Raspberry Pi is too complicated for your use case. I would suggest you look at an Arduino with a BLE capability. If you want to stick with Rasberry Pi then BLE is probably still the best way to go

Answer (score 0):

Are the lights you want to turn on/off wired to the Raspberry Pi (for example via GPIO)? 
You need to install one of the open source automation software (like OpenHAB or Home Assistant, etc.). Disable port forwarding to the Raspberry Pi (usually you need to do this port forwarding, so here you don't need to do anything).
In this case, the IP is a local IP, and you get local access only. 
Then probably you need is already implemented by someone from the community, or you need to develop a simple script to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned playing sounds, you need a beeper (if those sounds are more complicated, use a speaker). Also, you need those lights connected to GPIO (USB is also a viable option, by simply turning on/off the USB port).

> Issuing a USB Hub class request (CLEAR_FEATURE PORT_POWER) to port 2 on the LAN9514 will > deactivate the USB output power switch.
>
> There's an app for that:
>
> https://github.com/codazoda/hub-ctrl.c

This is a bit harder to setup, but you don't need any soldering with this. Then, you need to setup an AP for the kids to connect to the Raspberry Pi's website (should be a website, app is harder to make). Also why you don't want the Raspberry Pi to connect to the internet?

Comment: For security reasons and having to maintain a server. It is simpler if I keep everything local. I will be using a speaker and GPIO

Comment: Should be easy to do. Use a Raspberry Pi relay board to switch the light on/off. I have found [this](https://www.waveshare.com/rpi-relay-board.htm). As far as I know, this board should include some software pre-written to turn it off, or you could find some.

Comment: switching the lights on and off I can do easily. What I want to do is do it through a phone. I am surprised there is no easy way to this. I dont want to use an api service.

Comment: You don't need to use an API service. I absolutely do not understand why you are scared of making it non-local. Oh, now I understand, you want to do it through a phone. By what process you turn on/off those lights? If it's a simple HTTP request, it's easy to make an app for that.